# Is it possible to do a password input when using cordova-plugin-dialogs

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, apache-cordova

I have a JavaScript app which I use on multiple platforms with Cordova.
Due to some complications with native text boxes, I use [`cordova-plugin-dialogs`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/) on most input tags. WHen the user focuses, I bring forward the `prompt`. It looks something like this:

```
navigator.notification.prompt(message, function (result) {
         // do stuff
        }, document.title, undefined, myDefaultText)
```

Unfortunately I have run into a bit of a problem: I have one that needs to be a password. Which, according to the documentation, doesn't seem to be supported by the cordova-plugin-dialogs. Is there a way around this? Something I could pass in or another plugin I need to be able to hide the password as it is being typed in these dialogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with `cordova-plugin-dialogs`.
There were 2 Pull Requests adding it, but it was never merged. You can try with [this one](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/pull/71) that added to iOS and Android

Comment: Thanks. That is good to know. To add to your answer in case other people also need to know this, I also found [this plugin](https://github.com/Justin-Credible/cordova-plugin-password-dialog) which currently does solve the problem.